# WSO2 when I am running on MAC OS X Maverics, I am seeing strange ip address used by WSO2AS and WSO2AM,

Tags: macos, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-as

May I know how to configure to use my local ip address 192.168.2.1, initially it worked like that only but when started AS and AM one after one I am getting like this.

```
[2013-11-22 21:18:25,123]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : http://strange ip address:9763/publisher

[2013-11-22 21:18:25,123]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : http://strange ip address:9763/store
```

where strange ip address is 100.107.140.34. Not sure from where it is getting this ip address.

I am using MAC OS X Maverics(10.9), when I use ip address as localhost, I am able to login into api manager using publisher or store with account admin, also I am able to login into Application server using admin account, but I am not able to login into PizzaShack sample
 using the same credentials.

Please advice

Comment: 100.107.140.34 is SHared ADdress space, used with Address translation.  Try doing an ifconfig -a in the command prompt to see which interface was assigned that. I am guessing it is coming from your ISP, or a wireless connection.

Comment: To bind entire API Manager to the public IP, you have to change HostName and MgtHostName elements giving your public IP. <HostName>{publicIP}</HostName> and <MgtHostName>{publicIP}</MgtHostName>. These are defined in <APIM>/repository/conf/carbon.xml, and are commented by default. – mentioned by @AmilaDeSilva resolved the ip address issue

Comment: @doon, I found the ip address mapping with ifconfig -a but  I am not able to reach that ip address.